# Typealias with structs

Tags: generics, swift

Is it possible to use `typealias` in `structs` or `classes`? For example:

```
struct Foo {
    typealias type = Int
}
```

This compiles without error. However, when I use this struct:

```
let f = new Foo
let bar: f.type
```

This gives me a:

> Use of undeclared type 'f'

How can you retrieve this stored type?

This would be useful with generic structs, for example:

```
struct TypeHolder<T> {
    typealias type = T
}

let type1 = new TypeHolder<Int>
let fooint: type1.type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

You're making two small mistakes:

- Don't use `new`.
- Access the type using the class name, not the instance.

#### Example:

```
struct Foo {
    typealias type = Int
}

let f = Foo()
let bar: Foo.type = 5
```

Comment: Is this possible with generics?

Comment: Yes, but you have to type `Foo<T>.type` so no typing saved in this simple case. :)